# Trying to do a simple regex

Tags: python, regex

i wan to extract (abc)(def) using the regex 
which i ended up with that error below

import re

```
def main():
    str = "-->(abc)(def)<--"

match = re.search("\-->(.*?)\<--" , str).group(1)

print match
```

The error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):    
  File "test.py", line 7, in <module>    
    match = re.search("\-->(.*?)\<--" , str).group()    
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 146, in search    
    return _compile(pattern, flags).search(string)    
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

Comment: ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​What are you trying to do actually? What's the expected output and the error? Have you tried `match = re.search([...]).group(1)`? Also remember put it into the `main` function and run the function.

Comment: sry wrong clicked and submitted the unfinished question

Comment: your indentation is wrong for search and print. The should be inside main()

Comment: so i put it in the main(): Why is there  no print at my terminal 
sry i am very new to python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Corrected:

```
import re
def main():
    my_string = "-->(abc)(def)<--"
    match = re.search("\-->(.*?)\<--" , my_string).group(1)
    print match
    # (abc)(def)

main()
```

Note, that I renamed `str` to `my_string` (do not use standard library functions as own variables!). Maybe you can still optimize your regex with lookarounds, the lazy star (`.*?`) can get very ineffective sometimes.

Comment: Thank you for the answer was looking around but didnt understand some other regex post